# Dropdown Items not getting reset after navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a StatefulWidget as my current dashboard page. I'm calling my backend in initState and i'm creating my dropdown items with the response. This part is working fine!

My problem is when i'm navigating away and coming back to my page, I get the following error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 5eb8e4670ae9b245c86b752b. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 827 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

After debuging, I saw that my dropdown kept the items from the last time, so when I return to my page and I try to generate my new Items from my backend, I can't because it's already inside the dropdown.

I would like to destroy my dropdown when navigating away, but I can't figure out how to do it, I'm already using dispose but it don't seem enough to reset my dropdown.

Here's my code for this page, I would appreciate a little help, Flutter is still new to me! Thank you!

**Dashboard:**

```
class MyDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  MyDashboardState createState() => MyDashboardState();
}

class MyDashboardState extends State<MyDashboard> {

  Future<List<dynamic>> loadAll() async {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    var model = Provider.of<DashboardModel>(context);

    try {
      final resp = await dio.post("/endpoint", data: {"date": date.millisecond});
      model.addArray(resp.data);
      return resp.data;

    } catch (err) {
      return Future.error(err);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      this.loadAll();
    });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var model = Provider.of<DashboardModel>(context);

    print('LIST LENGTH: ' + model.getList().length.toString());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _MyAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: model.getListAsItems().length == 0 ? KidCreate() : KidSelect(),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**KidSelect:**

```
class KidSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  _KidSelectState createState() => _KidSelectState();
}

String _mySelection;

class _KidSelectState extends State<KidSelect> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    list = new List();
    _mySelection = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildSelect() {

    var model = Provider.of<DashboardModel>(context);

    _mySelection = _mySelection == null ? model.getList()[0].id.toString() : _mySelection;
    list = model.getListAsItems();

    return DropdownButton<String>(
        hint: new Text("Select"),
        value: _mySelection,
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            _mySelection = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: list,
      );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildSelect(),
          ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are following the pattern where when you want to initialize the model, you are getting it from the provider and the provider being of global scope, it is not initializing the model but instead reusing an existing one. After you get hold of the model instance, you are fetching the data from API and appending the result, in this case, the model may contain the same data and it causes the mentioned error. Instead, I would suggest you call the API in case the model is empty, otherwise just reuse it

Comment: You can use a local scoped model instead of getting it from the provider, this way it never reuses.

Comment: @VilsadPP Thanks for your comment, I changed my code to stop using provider and keep it local and it worked! I don't think I need it global at the moment so I'll keep it like that! I didn't know that the provider would do this, and I didn't find anything, so I'm glad to finally be able to continue! Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Anyway, thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Vilsad P P comment, using a local state instead of a provider corrected the problem. But I later realised that I needed to use a provider because of some other functionnality I implemented, so I tried to find the reason why it wasn't working, and I think I found it!

When navigating away, the model provider dashboard was keeping my list in memory, so when I navigated back, it would add a second time the values to the list and would crash when creasting the dropdown. To prevent this, when I set the info from my api call to the model, instead of just adding, I reset the list before so the list is like new!

The other problem I had was with my selection by default of the dropdown, I tried to put the first item of my list as selected, but I did it too soon, before the list was fully created, so I changed the place I init the selection to be in the initState and I added await to the api call so it waits before assigning my first result!

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() async {
      await this.loadAll();
      var model = Provider.of<DashboardModel>(context);
      _mySelection = model.getList().length > 0 ? model.getList()[0].id.toString() : null;
    });
  }
```

Everything seems to work the way it should now! Thanks to Vilsad I was able to better understand how flutter works!